# Richards rule melting enthalpy

Tags: thermodynamics, metals

I know that Richard's rule states that entropy of fusion is constant for metals, and that it is ~2.2 cal K-1 mol -1. I am struggling to find the origin of this statement, is it empirical? What is its derivation? And how does it relate to the melting enthalpy ranges for metals to be between 1-1.5R Tm?

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms12386 could be of interest. As would https://pubs.aip.org/aip/apl/article-pdf/doi/10.1063/5.0041604/14546435/083902_1_online.pdf - bottom line is Richard's rule was empirical. The second one from APL is a 'simple model for the entropy of melting of monatomic liquids" and the abstract states "It offers a simple, physical explanation for Richard’s melting rule and provides a material-dependent correction to
Trouton’s vaporization rule."